# Dans quel ordre enseigner le français ?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Mon petit-ami irlandais essaie de réapprendre le français et je me suis fait une mission de l'aider. Je suis italienne mais je suis née et j'ai vécu au Luxembourg, donc je le parle assez couramment moi-même. Je me suis proposée de l'aider, mais j'avoue que je ne connais pas grand chose à l'apprentissage d'une langue qui me vient naturellement.

Mon problème c'est que je ne sais pas dans quel ordre commencer à lui apprendre la langue. Je lui ai fait réviser l'alphabet et je lui ai fait faire des exercices de prononciation, car cette dernière était terrible et donc il ne pouvait pas réviser le vocabulaire, comme il lisait mal ! Il est au niveau archi-débutant.

Mais que faire après ceci ? J'ai décidé d'entamer le vocabulaire, petit à petit, d'abord *dans la maison* etc. Mais ensuite ? Quand est-ce qu'on commence les verbes ? Quand est-ce qu'on devrait réviser des adjectifs ? Et les conjugaisons ? Les fiches pédagogiques je les trouve, ce n'est pas un problème, mais **je ne sais pas dans quel ordre procéder.**

Sauriez-vous où trouver une fiche directive ou quelque plan de leçons ?

Comment: @Aerovistae Titles should be in the same language as the body.

Comment: I know that, but I feel that putting popular and important questions like this in French is severely disadvantageous to our site because it will attract *zero* search engine traffic. I think exceptions should be made.

Comment: Let's see what comes up-- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164124/is-it-better-to-put-question-titles-in-english

Answer (score 11):

I have been teaching myself French for a couple of years now, so I can give some advice from experience.

I started with fundamentals:

- noun genders + *le*, *la*, *les*, *un*, *une*
- *oui* – *non* – *peut-être*
- pronouns: *il*, *elle*, *ils*, *elles*, *tu*, *je*, *vous*, *nous*, difference between *tu* and *vous*
- definition of infinitive tense, make sure that basic concept is understood.
- *être*, *avoir*, *aller*
- present tense conjugation of -ER verbs, *parler*, *manger*, *regarder*, *aimer*.
- basic connecting words: *de*, *à*, *avec*, *et*, *ou*
- forming the negative with *ne* … *pas*
- common phrases:

  - *S'il vous plaît*
  - *Merci*
  - *Bonjour*
  - *Bonsoir*
  - *Ça va ? Ça va bien*, etc.
- asking questions with *Est-ce que…*
- titles: *Monsieur*, *Madame*, *Mademoiselle*
- saying *There is…* with *Il y a…*
- saying *It is* / *This is…* with *C'est…* and *Il/elle est…*
- colors
- count to twenty
- words for the most common nouns: car, house, boy, girl, kitchen, street, city, book, man, woman, bedroom, television, table, shirt, pants, shoes, etc.
- saying your name and asking someone else's name: *Je m'appelle Jorgi ! Comment tu t'appelles ?* Don't bother teaching *me/te* at this point.
- saying your age.
- saying/asking the time, date, day of the week.
- days of the week, months of the year.

Then I learned more extended fundamentals:

- Interrogatives: *qui*, *que/quoi*, *quel*, *où*, *comment*, *combien*, *pourquoi*
- more advanced negatives: *ne … jamais*, *ne … plus*, *ne … que*
- if statements with *si*
- *faire*. Explain that this verb is *not* used quite the same way as the English *to do* or the English *to make*, although it overlaps with both. Frankly, I consider *faire* to be a tricky and highly complex verb in its usage. It is a part of so many other expressions like *Il fait beau* or *faire un cadeau* that simply explaining it as equivalent to *to do* is very misleading. Use examples.
- reasoning: *car*, *parce que*
- possession: *mon*, *ma*, *mes*, *ton*, *ta*, *tes*, etc.
- This/that/these/those: *ce/cette/ces*, *ça*. It is a helpful tip early on to note that French does not differentiate between *this* and *that* to nearly the same extent that English does, because that is a major part of the English language and is a linguistic tool we are loathe to give up. Do not teach *cela/ceci* early on. Unnecessary. Also leave out *celui/celle/ceux/celles* until later.
- here/there: *ici* and *là*. Note that *là* is often used to mean *here*. I would avoid anything more than a very basic treatment of *y*, since it is not an easy word to grasp early on (I still don't know when to use it most of the time), and is more likely to be used wrong than right by the learner in many cases.
- other connecting words: *en*, *dans*, *comme*, *sur*, etc.
- inversion: *Avez-vous une bouteille ?*
- contractions: *au*, *aux*, *du*, *des*
- more basic nouns: trash, airplane, hat, cat, dog, etc. as many basics as you can fit into the learner's head. KEEP USING THE WORDS YOU LEARN. **DO NOT** teach something and then move on. Subsequent lessons *must* use past material.
- conjugation of regular -IR verbs. *choisir*, *finir*.
- more common regular -ER verbs. *donner*, *visiter*, *voyager*, *nager*, *étudier*, *garder*.
- count to 100
- more common phrases.
- passé composé and using *aller* to say *I'm going to do something.* also teach using être for certain verbs in the passé composé.
- basic adjectives and size words: *grand*, *petit*, *bien*, *mal*, *bon*, *peu*, *jeune*, *vieux*, *beaucoup*, etc.
- most common time words: *maintenant*, *puis*, *plus tard*, *matin*, *soir*, *jour*, *année*, *mois*, *semaine*, *heure*, *minute*, *temps*, etc.

I suppose I learned pronunciation as I went along. I learned each new word, and in so doing, I learned the rules that governed pronunciation. For example, “*suis*” is “swee”, and I learned there how to pronounce the `ui` sound as well as that the ending `s` is silent. Learn liaisons as you go, as well, and accent marks. Accent marks are easy to remember, really.

Show how all these things go together by teaching sample sentences of increasing complexity. Early on, start with things as simple as *Il aime la fille.* Later on: *Pourquoi est-ce que tu m'as donné un chien ?* and so on. *Il y avait dix-sept livres au-dessous la table, entre une chaise et la fournaise, et je les ai tous mis au feu.*

From there things get more complicated.

- *pouvoir*, *vouloir*, *devoir*, since they conjugate similarly, should be taught together, and are the three next most important irregular verbs after the 4 I named above.
- count to 999,999 (not a very difficult jump after getting to 100...only requires learning *mille*)
- more irregular verbs: highest priority should be *dire*, *comprendre*, and *savoir*. Then *prendre*, *mettre*, *voir*, *venir*, *tenir*, *partir*, *dormir*, etc. Show how families of irregular verbs are conjugated similarly. *Rendre* is good for that, since it has one of the largest (if not *the* largest) irregular families. See the note at the end for an addendum on this.
- more grammar.
- futur and imparfait. Save the subjunctive til WAY later. It's just not important until the person can communicate in the first place. **And don't even think about mentioning passé simple or imparfait du subjonctif. It can be intensely discouraging early on to realize that there are 7 separate conjugation sets plus composed tenses and present participle. Some people will give up.** In fact, don't mention the subjunctive either. If the learner discovers these other tenses, smile and tell him to ignore them *entirely.*
- direct objects, indirect objects, reflexive verbs
- *quelqu'un*, *rien*, *tout*, *chaque*, other similar helpful words.
- *y* and *en* as… what are they, pronouns? Explain basic usage. These are fairly challenging words, comparatively. It is difficult to know when to use them.

Here is the essential thing: *it gets easier the longer you do it.* At the beginning, the learner will have to force himself to remember so much new vocabulary. Later on, the learner will be forming a sentence and will find himself missing a word and will simply ask *Comment dit-on « horse » ?* and you will tell him, and he will be able to construct the sentence on his own, and will thereafter remember the word for horse. Your mind picks up momentum the longer it rolls.

That's probably a good starting point. Good luck. I welcome additions to my lists here. I know there are things I'm forgetting.

---

**Note:** When I was taught French verbs, I was taught that there are three regular conjugations: -ER, -IR, and -RE verbs like *rendre*, and everything else is irregular. **I do not recommend this whatsoever.** [Here](http://www.frenchtutorial.com/standard/present/group3_list.php) is a nearly complete list of French irregular verbs, and as you can see, the *rendre* family (by comparison to the regular -ER family or regular -IR family, each of which include several thousand verbs) is not *nearly* large enough to be eligible for consideration as its own regular conjugation.

Instead, I recommend this approach. There are *two* regular conjugations, -IR and -ER, and *all other verbs are irregular and must be memorized by family, rendre included. All -RE verbs are irregular.* Though the task of learning all the irregular verbs initially seems daunting, the patterns soon become self evident and simple to remember.

Comment: How did I get a bounty out of this?? Where did that come from?

Comment: Ah, that's my fault O:) What you describe with "*two* regular conjugations" is canonically called first and second group of verbs, in French, the “third group” being as you reckoned mostly a big bag of vaguely-sorted-by-family exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

Quand j'avais enseigné le français à ma femme qui parle maintenant très bien (elle a aussi reçu des cours depuis), je voulais qu'elle puisse rapidement faire des phrases et communiquer, et je voulais qu'elle parle comme tout le monde, pas de façon trop académique.

Au tout début, on avait commencé par:

- La prononciation et les règles de lectures à fond.
- le verbe être et les pronoms, avec quelques adjectifs et noms très utiles: « *je suis (pas) content* », « *Je suis là* », « *Je suis chez moi* », pour qu'elle puisse commencer à parler.
- les questions sans inversion. « *Tu es là?* », « *Tu es à la maison?* »
- les verbes avoir et aller, pour pouvoir faire le passé et le futur: « *j'ai mangé* », « *je vais voir une amie* »,…
- les expressions et verbes courants: *il y a*, *vouloir*, *pouvoir*, *avoir faim/mal/sommeil/peur/envie de*
- …

De manière générale, quand j'écoutais les gens parler, j'essayais de remarquer les trucs très utiles, et les notais pour les expliquer plus tard.

Je vous conseille de demander à votre petit ami ce qu'il a envie de dire, et de lui apprendre ça dans cet ordre, c'est comme ça qu'il sera le plus motivé pour utiliser ce qu'il a appris. Ou alors, vous écoutez ce qu'il dit en anglais, et vous luis dites comment le dire en français.

Et puis, un peu plus tard, c'est bien, je pense, de lire un livre facile ensemble (par exemple: le petit prince), ou une série télé quand il aura un meilleur niveau, quelque chose qui lui donne envie de savoir la fin.

Comment: +1 pour ` je voulais qu'elle parle comme tout le monde, pas de façon trop académique.`

Answer (score 0):

Pourquoi ne pas utiliser les méthodes pragmatiques (genre méthode « *My tailor is rich* ») fondées sur des exemples et puis, une fois que la petite musique de la phrase est mémorisée, expliquer les accords, les exceptions, essayer de donner l'origine des mots, comment ils ont évolué d'un coté et de l'autre.

Il existe des recueils d'expressions bilingues qu'il est très utile de connaître pour comprendre une conversation.
Les « chansons à texte » françaises sont aussi bon moyen de transmettre à la fois du texte (du sens, de la sensibilité, des mouvements subtils de la formulation de la pensée) et des mots pour échanger au quotidien.
Quelques poèmes choisis (je pense à Prévert, mais l'éventail est immense, de Louise Labé à…)

Pour lui, il faut qu'il puisse exprimer ses sentiments dans une langue que le monde entier trouve « glamour ».
Ensuite, s'il est obligé d'écrire, des dictées sont nécessaires, peut-être des cours par correspondance.

Il n'y a pas vraiment d'ordre, juste votre envie de lui faire découvrir ce qui est immédiatement compréhensible, de le raccrocher à un texte, à un article de journal, à une chanson… ne pas forcément partir des mots, mais d'une situation, d'une idée dont on fait le tour, que l'on rapproche de ce qui est déjà connu, et qui au fil du temps augmente le vocabulaire, la maîtrise de la grammaire.

Pas de contraintes ou d'obligations, mais profiter de la mémoire affective qui se souvient d'un moment pour y intégrer le langage.

**EDIT** *suite au commentaire* de @NikanaReklawyks.

Je n'ai pas voulu faire de publicité, mais tout le monde comprendra la référence.
C'est l'apprentissage de tout langage, où l'on se retrouve comme un bébé, dans un monde sonore déstabilisant.
Ici l'apprenti se trouve dans un contexte affectif très motivant, et le seul ordre qu'il va percevoir, c'est celui fourni par les expériences successives qu'il va être obligé de rencontrer.
Un noyau va se structurer à partir de cette conscience (faite d'expériences sonores, tactiles, olfactives,…) rattachée sans intermédiaire à des phonèmes nouveaux.
De là on peut objectiver le langage, et passer à l'abstraction grammaticale, simple au début, puis encadrée par des règles, des usages… que l'on peut commencer à ordonner.

Répondre à la question, n'est pas de donner une méthode testée, validée (souvent au cours de plusieurs années) et employée par un professeur dans un cadre particulier de maître à disciple, mais de réinventer des « leçons », c'est-à-dire un mode de transmission des connaissances en s'aidant de son intuition, de son imagination, de sa créativité plutôt que de savoirs tout faits.

Le plus efficace est que l'apprenant fasse ses notes au fur et à mesure, apprenne le genre des mots en y accolant un adjectif usuel, une règle de grammaire en trouvant la fiche sur laquelle elle a déjà été expliquée, même si elle n'est pas au même temps ou si le complément n'est pas de même type.

Comme je le disais, le contexte émotionnel me semble très favorable à cette façon de procéder : sans ordre prévu, programmé, testé, validé, normé, mais en suivant l'ordre naturel des choses, c'est-à-dire celui de l'apprenant, puis en enrichissant de ce qui lui est peu ou pas connu.
C'est une question de maîtrise, d'être soi, alors les choses s'organisent en conséquence, l'inter-réactivité est optimale, et les progrès suivent.

Comment: Ça me semble pas très structuré, donc pour une question qui demande une fiche directive, pas top. J'aime bien l'idée, mais la question n'est pas là : si on voit comment la faire marcher, alors ça marche, mais sinon, alors on pose la question, et ceci n'y répond pas vraiment. Par ailleurs, il me semble que c'est mal adapté au niveau archi-débutant.

Comment: [Labé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louise_Lab%C3%A9), c'est Louise, pas Louis. À cette époque c'était très exceptionnel. Cela dit, je ne m'aventurerais pas à enseigner de la poésie en vieux français à un débutant.

Comment: @mouviciel - Merci [la touche pas assez appuyée]. Non pas tous mais vu le contexte, je pensais au sonnet XVIII. L'idée : à partir d'un plat, parler un peu de sa région d'origine, d'une facture aborder le répertoire administratif, d'un mot abstrait chercher dans Le Robert (mon préféré pour la clarté des définitions, les synonymes, le choix des exemples et autres aides à la prononciation, les habitants des villes, les conjugaisons .. sa francophonie) faire jeu de tout et puis prendre quelques notes pour mieux mémoriser les découvertes, comme elles surviennent ; sans jouer les professeurs.

Comment: Cette réponse est à 100 000 km de la plaque.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je me suis contenté de relire la première phrase : petit ami +  réapprendre. Sans chercher donner des conseils qui ne seraient pas adapté aux personnes. L'idée : dire à Leila qu'il n'est pas nécessaire de passer le CAPES pour être francophone, et que l'on peut transmettre la langue, sa saveur, ses subtilités de façon intuitive. Plus tard il pourra tel M.Jourdain  découvrir le mot prose, ou zeugma avec Pierre Desproges ; mais tout cela ne me semble pas très éloigné de l'expérience d'Aerovistae.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks bonne idée pour les 'bounty'. Vu les votes négatifs, cela permettra à Leila de nous dire où elle se sent le mieux : francophonie intuitive ou français académique, créativité ou normativité, .... avec, bien-sûr toutes les nuances possibles.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre… c'est moi qui alloue la prime que je mets sur la question, sauf erreur ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Exact. Me voila dans l'embarras. Sans gomme possible. Je vais donc rediriger mon interrogation, pour avoir l'avis de Leila, car il semble que mon expérience (avec des voisins de palier étrangers) soit aussi partagée par d'autres intervenants. D'autre part, l'attribution prématurée du bounty est plus que surprenante.

Comment: @Leila Vu les différents types de réponses, vous serait-ils possible de nous donner vos impressions, l'aide qu'elles ont pu vous apporter, ou si votre façon d'aborder le problème a évolué?