# Where can I find a well-organized free french lessons website?

Tags: ressources

I'm starting to grasp French, but in my journey of finding good resources I haven't been able to find a good site with a good structure of lessons. What I'm looking for is a French site with lessons organized like these good sites I used when learning Korean (off topic: I recommend them if you're interested)

http://www.talktomeinkorean.com

http://www.howtostudykorean.com

Lessons are well structured according to your level, and they are also very well written in order to learn the basics of language, and even the intermediate and advanced stuff. What is more interesting is that many of the lessons are free, with the option to access a paid option in the first one and a donation-like option in the second one, but even without paying the lessons they offer are quite good.

In summary, I'm looking for a free French course split into level-or-progress-according lessons and very easy to understand, similar to the sites I referenced.

Comment: I wouldn't ask "where can I find" so much as "does it exist", especially if you want it for free. That being said, maybe you'll be interested in [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4660/dans-quel-ordre-enseigner-le-fran%C3%A7ais), basically about what lessons would fall into what level. Maybe you can build your own curriculum off it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Duolingo? They have French language courses in various first languages.

Comment: I've heard from various people that Duolingo might not get you to much proficiency though... Just relating what I have heard, I would like to hear other opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I can second the comment that Duolingo is not the best resource to improve proficiency. I use duolingo daily for French. I think its great to do quick exercises, brush up on vocabulary, and be used as a supplementary to your studies. Duolingo also has a product called Duolingo Stories and that is another great supplementary tool for learning as well. I found these websites to be somewhat helpful but the organization is kind of confusing:

https://apprendre.tv5monde.com/

https://www.newsinslowfrench.com/